Make sense of decompressed xref data from PDF
I try to read in a PDF in binary format and parse its information.
I can parse most objects, including using zlib to decompress FlateDecoded data.
But when I try to parse the compressed xref data, I cannot make sense of the decompressed data.
I am using this pdf as a test.
The xref starts at 343543, where the PDF object starts with a length of 5906 using /Filter /FlateDecode.
When I decompress the stream, I get the following values (shown are only the first 100, total length is 12625): b'\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff\x02\x00\x00\x02\x00\x01\x00\x00\x0f\x00\x02\x00\x01\x98\x0c\x02\x00\t;\x10\x02\x00\x00\x02\x01\x02\x00\x00\x02\x02\x02\x00\x01\x98-\x02\x00\t;\x0f\x02\x00\x00\x02\x03\x02\x00\x00\x02\x04\x02\x00\x01\x98>\x02\x00\t;\x0e\x02\x00\x00\x02\x05\x02\x00\x00\x02\x06\x02\x00\x01\x98V\x02\x00\t;\r\x02\x00\x00\x02\x07\x02\x00\x00\x02\x08\x02\x00\x01\x98['
I have used mutool to clean the pdf, where I see the cleaned and decompressed xref as a benchmark as
xref
0 2525
0000000002 00256 f 
0000000016 00000 n 
0000000203 00001 f 
0000000069 00000 n 
0000000134 00000 n 
0000000215 00000 n 
0000000262 00000 n 
0000000321 00000 n 

MWE
To replicate the values, I use this python code
import zlib
file = "pdf/dplyr.pdf"
with open(file, "rb") as f:
    data = f.read()
xref_text = data[slice(343543, 349686)]
stream = xref_text[slice(220, 6127)]
stream = zlib.decompress(stream)
stream[:100]

and mutool clean -d dplyr.pdf dplyr_clean.pdf and then in line 37521ff I see the parsed xref data as shown above.

Don't be sure that the xref table mupdf creates will be the same - PDF objects might have been rewritten or reordered, depending on how mupdf is written. A cross-reference stream is not just a cross-reference table compressed by a standard filter. To understand the cross-reference stream format, See 7.5.8 "Cross Reference Streams" in the ISO standard for PDF.

First of all, the xref table you got by using mutool cannot possibly represent the same data as the cross reference stream you're interested in. Your original PDF contains object streams, and references to objects in object streams cannot be represented in cross reference tables, only in cross reference streams. Thus, you will hardly find any semblance in your extracted cross reference stream and in that cross reference table.
To make sense of the binary data you got have a look at the dictionary of that cross reference stream:
<<
/Type /XRef
/Index [0 2525]
/Size 2525
/W [1 3 1]
/Root 2522 0 R
/Info 2523 0 R
/ID [<BB37DE0AA29BF8A5A0ABF4B186CED3DB> <BB37DE0AA29BF8A5A0ABF4B186CED3DB>]
/Length 5906      
/Filter /FlateDecode
>>

First of all you see that you don't have any DecodeParms in it, so there in particular is no Predictor defined. Thus, the binary data you got already are the final cross reference information, they don't need to be decoded using a Predictor algorithm anymore.
Second, you have a W entry of [1 3 1], so each entry in your stream consists of 5 bytes, a single-byte type field and two data fields, 3 and 1 bytes in length respectively.
Finally, there is an Index entry of [0 2525]. Thus, there are entries of objects 0 through 2524 in your stream.
Let's look at the first entries in your stream:



Raw Data
Prettified
Meaning




\x00\x00\x00\x00\xff
00 000000 FF
Object 0 is free with a generation number of 255, a cut-down version of the analog 0000000000 65535 f xref table entry.


\x02\x00\x00\x02\x00
02 000002 00
Object 1 is packed in the object stream 2 at index 0.


\x01\x00\x00\x0f\x00
01 00000F 00
Object 2 is a regular object at offset 15 with a generation number of 0.


\x02\x00\x01\x98\x0c
02 000198 0C
Object 3 is packed in the object stream 408 at index 12.


...
...
...



You can find this all explained in the PDF specification (either ISO 32000-1 or ISO 32000-2) section 7.5.8.
